# Apparent inconsistency in the expectation of max of IID RVs

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are $n$ IID RVs. $Z = \mathrm{max}(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$.

Now define $I$ as follows:
$I = i$ when $X_i$ is the maximum of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$.
Using law of total expectation we can write
$$
E[Z] = E[E[Z|I]] = E[X_I] = E[X]
$$
This says that $Z$ and any $X_i$ have the same expectation. But it can be shown that the CDF of $Z$ is $F_X^n$. This is contradictory as it suggests that RVs with CDFs $F$ and $F^n$ for any integer $n$ have the same expectation which is false for the simple case of $U(0, 1)$ RVs.

What is wrong with the application of law of total expectation above?

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the law of total expectation. Rather, it's the claim $\mathbb{E}[X_I] = \mathbb{E}[X]$ that is false, because your index is a function of all $X$s.

In fact, you can skip the law of total expectation altogether, and use the definition definition of $I$ to write $Z = X_I$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z] = \mathbb{E}[X_I]$.

EDIT: Here's some more details about the expectation of $X_I$. Here I use $J(I=i)$ for the indicator function as $I$ is already used.

$$\mathbb{E}[X_I] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i J(I=i)]$$

Due to the symmetric setting, $I$ is uniformly distributed. If, in some other setting, $J(I=i)$ and $X_i$ were independent, we could then continue 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i J(I=i)] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i]\mathbb{P}[I=i] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}{X_i} = \mathbb{E}[X]$$

However, in our problem this is not the case. $I$ is a function of $(X_1 \dots X_n)$ - it's the index of the maximum. Therefore, they're highly correlated instead: The larger $X_i$ is, the more likely it is that $I=i$.

Comment: Since $X_1, X_2, \dots$ all have identical distribution, $E[X_1] = E[X_2] = \dots = E[X_n]$

Comment: @Priyatham That means $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mathbb{E}[X]$ for any **constant** $i$. But it's not true for a **random variable** $I$, or for a integer-valued function $f(X_1, \dots X_n)$.